# NI-VISA library programming in C++ - out of scope error

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, codeblocks, visa

I am currently trying to program a Rigol DS1054 Oscilloscope to output waveform data. To create this program, I am writing in C++ using Code::Blocks, but I have tried this on four other compilers (Netbeans, Eclipse Mars, Eclipse Juno, Visual Basic 2012) but each one continuously results in an error. Here is what I have done so far:

- Confirmed that C++ was not the problem by building and running a Hello World program
- Linked the header file following this path *(C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Include)*
- Linked the library using this path *(C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\lib\msc\visa32.lib)*
- Applied the library for each project

I have also tried using the 64-bit version as well an I get the same error. This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <visa.h>
using namespace std; 

int main () {

   ViSession rmSession;
   ViOpenDefaultRM(&rmSession);

   return 0;
}
```

The code is very simple, but when run, returns this error:

```
error: 'ViOpenDefaultRm' was not declared in this scope
```

This is really weird since it is clearly in the scope. This has been giving me trouble for so many days now - any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `#import` isn't standard C++. Maybe try with `#include`?

Comment: I did, I accidentally wrote import down by accident

Comment: visa.h follows a convention of beginning types with an uppercase letter and functions with a lowercase letter, and constants are all uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called `viOpenDefaultRM`, not `ViOpenDefaultRM`.

For the avoidance of your confusion by such errors in future,
the `ViOpenDefaultRM(&rmSession)` in your code is not a *declaration* of
a function, it is an invocation or call of a function (or would be, if such
a function existed).

In C++, the compiler must see a *declaration* of a function
before it will permit invocations of that function, so that it can tell
whether the invocation conforms to the function's signature (or to one of
the signatures of an overloaded function), and the declaration must be
still in scope at the point of invocation.

The declaration of `viOpenDefaultRM` is:

```
ViStatus _VI_FUNC  viOpenDefaultRM (ViPSession vi);
```

You will find it in `visa.h`, and it is in scope at the point where you
have attempted to call `ViOpenDefaultRM` because, by including `visa.h`
before you define `main`, it is declared in the scope enclosing `main`,
i.e. in global scope.

Comment: Perfect. You have no idea how long I have been struggling with this. Thank you so much!